# Get information from JSON file and use that data in the attributes of a singleton class

Tags: java, json, gson, singleton

I have a singleton class that looks like this

```
public class Config {
    private static Config instance;
    int weight;
    String color;

    private Config(){}

    public static Config getInstance(){
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new Config();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }

    public int getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
}
```

What i want to do is create a JSON file that looks this:

```
{"weight":22,"color":#RRGGBB}
```

and then extract the valus for the weight and the color from the file and then set those 2 values for the variables String color and int weight in my class.
I tried something similar to this:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("./config.json");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
json = gson.toJson(in.readObject());
Config.getInstance() = gson.fromJson(json,Config.class); //?????
```

The problem I have is on the last line of code. I don't understand how to use the fromJson() function to make it work with a singleton class instance.

I would like to output something like this

```
System.out.println(Config.getInstance().getColor()+ " "+ Config.getInstance().getWeight());
```

And get a result like this :

```
#RRGGBB 22
```

Are there any ways to make is work? Are there any better methods for this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```java
Config configFromGson = gson.fromJson(json, Config.class);

// set values in singleton config
config.getInstance().setColor(configFromGson.getColor());
config.getInstance().setWeight(configFromGson.getWeight());
```